# wildfly or jboss 7.1 standalone.xml dtd

Tags: jboss7.x, wildfly

I understand that this question is not very specific to programming but I am trying to find the description of each tag in standalone.xml in wildfly or jboss 7.1 so that I can learn about each tag and it will be helpful for configuration.

Where can I find a document that describes tags used in standalone.xml? jBoss or Wildfly administration guide does not give all the information.

Comment: May be http://wildscribe.github.io/

Comment: that thing is EXTREMELY hard to read ... in fact is nigh-useless because its cluttered like hell

Answer (score 3):

James R. Perkins's right.
Under $JBOSS_HOME/docs/schema there are several schemas, which describe the tags of standalone.xml.
The table on https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/JBossDTDs denotes which 'DTD or Schema' applies to what xml.
For example, if You are curious about the 'logging' subsystem of standalone.xml, than look at $JBOSS_HOME/docs/schema/jboss-as-logging_1_1.xsd file.

Answer (score 2):

If you look in the `$JBOSS_HOME/docs/schema` there are several schemas that make up the standalone.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

you should start from $JBOSS_HOME/docs/schema/wildfly-config_5_0.xsd , there is the definition of the main types "domain", "host" and "server". Good luck!