# How To Bulk-Import XSDs

Tags: xml, intellij-idea, jboss, wildfly

This is a follow-up question to 
[wildfly or jboss 7.1 standalone.xml dtd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27836957/wildfly-or-jboss-7-1-standalone-xml-dtd)

And forgive me, I'm new here, I couldn't find a link to specifically ask a clarifying or follow-up question while **at that question**.

I'm in the process of converting from eclipse Mars to intellij IDEA.

I don't actually do java programming, but I work in a java house, and I do lots of configurations for java jars/wars deployed on JBoss/WildFly, and most of these configurations are XML. I'm finding intellij IDEA to be **stellar** for finding and fixing (or helping me fix) problems in XML.

Along the way, I also need to edit standalone.xml. A lot. Running intellij's validation against the out-of-the-can standalone.xml comes up with hundreds of errors, probably because no XSDs or DTDs are specifically called out at the top of the standalone.xml. It starts like this:

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:3.0">
  <extensions>
    <!-- ...snip-a-de-do-dah... -->
  </extensions>
</server>
```

```
schema $ pwd
/my/path/to.../wildfly-9.0.1.Final/docs/schema
schema $ find . -type f -name "*dtd" |wc -l
6
schema $ find . -type f -name "*xsd" |wc -l
383
schema $
```

Hundreds... literally hundreds of schema files potentially involved in describing and validating that one standalone.xml file.

tl;dr

Is there a way to bulk-import **all** the wildfly docs schema XSDs and DTDs into intellij so it **just works** for any possible wildfly-related validation of standalone.xml or hosts.xml files we might create/edit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Intellij now has a convenient option to import all those schemas, via the App Servers section. There is a "Register schemas" button you can click when adding a wildfly installation (in preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Application Servers).

I'm using Intellij Ultimate 2019.1.

See also [the docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/application-servers-settings.html) on this feature.

Comment: That's cool, IF I'm managing a tomcat or wildfly on my computer (as stated in the doc you linked). That is not our situation, but it might be worth installing WildFly 10.1 (or whatever) locally just so as to configure these plugins and whatnot in IDEA.

Therefore, I think this is THE answer (with that caveat).

Answer (score 0):

https://gist.github.com/kelvin0mql/34f8973ce85e71ae80e7

On the one hand, I did **not** find a way to bulk-import. I think it would be awesome if intellij provided a way to just point it at docs/schema and say "use all these as you deem appropriate". Alas, 'tis not to be.

On the other hand, I figured out how to do it the tedious, one-validation-error-at-a-time way. Then I posted a public gist to try to be helpful to the next poor sap who will most likely never find this.